# how to find number pattern in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am in the middle of completing some code, I almost finished my code but I am not posting that code here as that is huge, I am copying a class name from one div to another div and I want to extract a number from that class, the class always follow the below pattern. The class will always have ColorSlice before number and Mouseover after the number.

class names

```
ColorSlice1MouseOver
ColorSlice1MouseOver
ColorSlice12MouseOver
ColorSlice32MouseOver
```

I want to extract the number from that string in a elegant fashion using regex or so, I can write substring functions, but I thought there might be better way to do that.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this regex (assuming you have original css class name in Javascript variable **str**):

```
num = str.replace(/ColorSlice([0-9]+)MouseOver/, "$1");
```

Comment: +1 But I would add a `^` anchor to the start of the expression - this will allow it to fail quicker in the case of a non-match. Details, details...

Comment: @ridgerunner: would you? Who says he's not using multiple classes like `class="something ColorSlice11MouseOver"`?

Comment: @ridgerunner: I agree regex can be like this `num = c.replace(/^ColorSlice([0-9]+)MouseOver$/, "$1")` if variable str is just **"ColorSlice32MouseOver"**
But I wasn't sure how is OP getting these strings in JS variable, eg: having ^ and $ won't work if str = **" ColorSlice32MouseOver"**

Comment: @anubhava , those are the class names of a div , i click on a div and want to grab the class name as it contains the color id,

Comment: In that case I would not suggest having ^ at the start and $ at the end of regex. Because div element can have more than 1 css class names as *Robert Koritnik* has also pointed in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
"ColorSlice1MouseOver".replace("ColorSlice", "").replace("MouseOver", "");
```

Comment: both the answers are working , but planning to learn regex a bit , thanks for your answer shah

Comment: this won't work when there'd be a string `ColorSliceOneMouseOver` @anubhava's answer works for number only.

Comment: @Robert , for me there will be always number between those strings , so i will take that answer for now , thanks once again robert.

Comment: @Robert: Here is what OP wrote: The class will always have ColorSlice before **number** and Mouseover after the number.